# How to add the ojdbc jar to my project and use it

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, jar

I need some help with the eclipse.

I have a project which need to connect to oracle databases so i have the ojdbc jar file and a simple project.

```
try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+this.host+":"+this.port+":"+this.db,this.user,this.pass);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (rset.next())
        {
            retStr += rset.getString(1) + ',';
        }
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }
```

and I got an exception that the `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` is not exists.
how do I add the jar to my project and use it?

I did this step and I still get the exception.
You will have to add the jar to your Classpath. You can do that in eclipse by right clicking on the Project --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path

Answer (score 4):

You will have to add the jar to your Classpath. You can do that in eclipse by right clicking on the Project --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path

Under Libraries tab, click Add Jars and give the Jar (oracle jdbc driver).

Oracle JDBC Driver download [here](http://download.oracle.com/otn/utilities_drivers/jdbc/10204/ojdbc14.jar)

Comment: I did it but It doesn't work. the exception still exist. the jar is inside my project and i did what you've said.

Comment: Can you please let me know what file you're using for the jar ?

Answer (score 3):

Ok. finally The solution is to add the jar file into the Web-Inf/lib directory because I have a Dynamic web application.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

In my Java projects, I create a `/lib` directory at the same level as `/src` and `/bin`. I throw any library jars in there and then right-click on the `.jar` file and do "Build Path | Add to Build Path."

Comment: I did this step and I get the same exception

Comment: You didn't mention (until an hour later) that it's a Web application. I guess we should have asked. But I'm glad to see you got it resolved meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

**To Add ojdbc14.jar file into the project**
In Eclipse under project folder->WEB-INF->lib then Right click lib folder-> Build Path->Configure Build Path->Under Libraries->Click on Add External Jars->Computer->Local Disk (C:)->oraclexe->app->oracle->product->10.2.0->server->jdbc->lib->now select ojdbc14.jar

Directly the path is C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar

Answer (score 0):

Always use the latest JDBC driver.

Refer to this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/index-3093936.html)  where all Java developer tools are described on how to choose the JDBC drivers.