# Error while making connection to Oracle database in JDBC

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

I have written a code to check whether connection is successful or not.
But its giving error.
I have a **oracle 10g express edition** instsalled on my computer.

```
try{
String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521:XE";
String driver= "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
Class.forName(driver);
System.out.println(" Driver loaded ");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"system:,"manager");
System.out.println("Connection Successful");
} //catch block
```

The error given is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193849/how-to-add-the-ojdbc-jar-to-my-project-and-use-it

Comment: You need to mention which IDE you are using.

Comment: Drop the jar with the driver in your project, right click on it and add it to the Build Path.  Try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add **ojdbc.jar** in classpath.

Check this for [How to Add JARs to Project Build Paths in Eclipse](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29)

Comment: Download this http://findjar.com/jar/mule/dependencies/maven1/oracle-jdbc/jars/ojdbc14.jar.html

Answer (score 1):

you need to add oracle jdbc driver (jar) to your class path.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the JAR file containing the `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` class is simply not on your classpath. Find it and fix that problem by adding the location (e.g., via the `-cp` option to `java`; the details of how to fix it will vary by the kind of application you're building).

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `oracle_jdbc.jar` file in the same folder of your code, or anywhere else and add that folder to your classpath.