# Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, nullpointerexception

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

is throwing `NullPointerException`, I have tried a lot to solve it but failed.

You can check following function where the problem is occuring:

```
public static Connection con=null;

public static Connection getOracleConnection()
{


    try{  
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe",Constants.OracleUsername,Constants.OraclePassword);  
        }catch(NullPointerException npe){ npe.printStackTrace(); }
    catch(Exception e){ System.out.println("Error to create the connection "); }

    return con;
}
```

Comment: the oracle driver is in your lib folder?

Comment: As Stefan said,  the ojdbc jar needs to be on the class path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while making connection to Oracle database in JDBC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298287/error-while-making-connection-to-oracle-database-in-jdbc)

Comment: @StefanBeike if the driver was not on their classpath then `Class.forName()` would throw a CNFE not a NPE

Comment: Please provide us the stack trace

Comment: done :) thanks it is running fine now

Comment: @RavirajDarade Don't forget to either provide your solution and accept it as an answer or accept any proposed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the Oracle JDBC driver is in your classpath.

You can find one on the page below if not yet downloaded:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html