# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/gfas1/Desktop/st.accdb

Tags: java, ms-access, connection

So I'm trying to set up the connection in access database but otherwise fails.
I have imported the ucanaccess 5 files already and I'm confused why this doesn't work.
[Here are the jars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKoyV.png)

```
public class Access {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/gfas1/Desktop/st.accdb");
        Statement stment = conn.createStatement();
        String qry = "SELECT * FROM Students";

        ResultSet rs = stment.executeQuery(qry);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            String id    = rs.getString("ID") ;
            String fname = rs.getString("Name");

            System.out.println(id + fname);
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: you should try to add jar files to classpath "by choosing option add as library" on your development environment, putting jar files only won't help you in the way that they will be available for your project. Here it is describe in better ways with many options https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193849/how-to-add-the-ojdbc-jar-to-my-project-and-use-it

Answer (score 0):

JDBC driver should be loaded and you should have driver jar in your classpath

> Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");

In this case driver registers itself and Java knows how to handle those database connection.

also see http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html

Comment: how do i find out com.your? you mean which driver?

Comment: I updated the package for you case. Just add it before DriverManager.getConnection() call

Comment: But all the tutorials said that in this java version, no need for the line class.forName

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver

Comment: You must add the ucanaccess jar to the classpath and call Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver"); before you try to open the connection. see http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html

Comment: what if my classpath is locked by the administrator? i have no permission to access it

Comment: it worked!! i was adding the java jars in the wrong project.lol